# Laravel Passport::Route in version 11

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Just upgrade Laravel Passport from v10 to v11.
It seems like it does not support Passport::Route anymore.

I did read the documentation but did not understand how to rewrite te code below.

```
Passport::routes(
        function (RouteRegistrar $router) {
            $router->forAccessTokens();
            $router->forTransientTokens();
        },
        [
            'prefix' => 'api/oauth',
        ]
    );
```

So this worked fine in v10. Does anyone know how i need to write the code, to make it work with v11?

Answer (score 0):

here are the upgrade guidelines:
https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/11.x/UPGRADE.md

The laravel/passport package has moved all router configuration into a separate file `vendor/laravel/passport/routes/web.php` which will be loaded automatically by default. That's why you, in most cases, can remove all these `Passport::routes` method from your code.

`$route->forAccessTokens()` has added all these `authorize` routes to laravel. Please have a look into the `web.php` file and you will see: it's already there.

After removing all `Passport::routes` from your project, please clear cache and check `artisan route:list`, if all routes are still registered.

You have a special case. You have configured a prefix `api/oauth`, but the default of laravel/passport is just `oauth`. Please check, if you can live and adapt the new path. Else, you have to override routing of laravel/passport. Copy over all routes from laravel/passport `web.php` into your own `web.php` and deactivate loading of passports default routes:

Add the `ignoreRoutes` line to your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function register(): void
{
    Passport::ignoreRoutes();
}
```

All that is described here:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport#overriding-routes